# Upload image into server with form in android

Tags: android, forms, image-uploading

I have a form to upload an image and other details. Now I am sending all the form details with image but, after clicking the submit button I am saving all the form details with image into database.

While debugging image path was showing but I am getting an unfortunately error.

Can any one please help me?

**Java code:**

```
public class AccountFragment extends Fragment {

    public AccountFragment() {
    }

    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    String ba1;
    public static String URL = "url";
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
    String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    String companyname, personname, address, locality, city, pincode, contact1, contact2, username, password, confirm_password;
    EditText company_name, person_name, address1, locality1, city1, pincode1, contact11, contact21, contact31, username1, password1, confirm_password1;
    Button btpic, add, gallery, btnup;

    //ImageView upload_camera;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_account, container, false);

        btpic = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.upload);
        gallery = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        mImageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_upload);

        company_name = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edtCompany);
        person_name = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edtName);
        address1 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edtAddress);
        locality1 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edtLocality);
        city1 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textCity);
        pincode1 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edtPin);
        contact11 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edtContact1);
        contact21 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edtContact2);
        contact31 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edtContact3);
        username1 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edtusername);
        password1 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edtpassword);
        confirm_password1 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edtcpassword);
        add = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
        Button submit = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonsubmit);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                contact31.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                add.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        btpic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                captureImage();

            }
        });


        gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                //startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);


            }
        });

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // selectedImagePath=upload_camera.
                companyname = company_name.getText().toString();
                personname = person_name.getText().toString();
                address = address1.getText().toString();
                locality = locality1.getText().toString();
                city = city1.getText().toString();
                pincode = pincode1.getText().toString();
                contact1 = contact11.getText().toString();
                contact2 = contact21.getText().toString();
                username = username1.getText().toString();
                password = password1.getText().toString();
                confirm_password = confirm_password1.getText().toString();
                upload();

            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }


    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    private void upload() {

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bao);
        byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
        ba1 = Base64.encodeBytes(ba);
        new uploadToServer().execute();
    }

    private void captureImage() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {

            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (photoFile != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1);
            }
        }
    }


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            setPic();
        }
    }

    public class uploadToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        private ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity().getBaseContext());

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd.setMessage("Wait image uploading!");
            pd.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(Void... Params) {

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("base64", ba1));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Image", System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",personname));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address",address));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("locality",locality));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city",city));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pin",pincode));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone1",contact1));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone2",contact2));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("companyName",companyname));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));






            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                String st = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                Log.v("log_tag", "In the try Loop" + st);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            }
            return "Success";

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pd.hide();
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }
    private void setPic(){
        int targetW =mImageView.getWidth();
        int targetH=mImageView.getHeight();

        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions =new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds=true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath,bmOptions);
        int photoW=bmOptions.outWidth;
        int photoH=bmOptions.outHeight;

        int scaleFactor =Math.min(photoW/targetW,photoH/targetH);

        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds=false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize=scaleFactor;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable=true;


        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath,bmOptions);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException{

        Calendar someDate = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        someDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -7);

        String timeStamp=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName="JPEG_"+ timeStamp +  "-";
        File storageDir= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image =File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg",storageDir);

        mCurrentPhotoPath=image.getAbsolutePath();
        Log.e("GetPath","Cool"+mCurrentPhotoPath);
        return image;
    }
```

**Logcat:**

```
08-24 15:05:03.882  27486-27486/com.example.adaptiz.demo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.adaptiz.demo, PID: 27486
    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:591)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:260)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
            at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.AccountFragment$uploadToServer.onPreExecute(AccountFragment.java:188)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
            at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.AccountFragment.upload(AccountFragment.java:153)
            at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.AccountFragment.access$100(AccountFragment.java:43)
            at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.AccountFragment$4.onClick(AccountFragment.java:128)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4444)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18440)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: try to put `e.printStackTrace()` in the catch block and you may get the real exception.. Also create the `ProgressDialog` inside the `onPreExecute()` method

Answer (score 1):

If your ***activity* *class extends Activity***, you can get application context using [getApplicatoinContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html). But this method won’t be available when your **Activity extends from Fragment**.

When your activity extends Fragment, use [getActivity ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) [instead `getApplicatoinContext`() ] to get the context of the activity.

Answer (score 0):

yes thanks for the help it's working instead of getactivity().getApplicationContext() only getActivity()